# If all values of X are between a and b, show that the expected value of X is between a and b.

Tags: probability

The exact wording of the question was

> if $a \le X \le b$, show that $a \le E(X) \le b$.

where E in this context means the expected value. Intuitively this seems true but I don't know how to show (prove?) it. My first thought was to show that the minimum and maximum values of $E(X)$ are $a$ and $b$ respectively, but then I have to show that

$pmf(X)=\begin{cases}x=a & 1 \\ otherwise & 0 \end{cases}$

actually is the distribution that produces the minimal value for $E(X)$ and the opposite for b, which doesn't seem like a much better situation. Is there a straightforward way to show these are the minimum and maximum values for $E(X)$ or is there a better way to go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**
Consider the full definition of expected value, that is
$$E[X] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f(x)dx$$
or in the discrete case$$ E[X] = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}x_ip_i$$
And use the monotonicity of the integral (or sum), which is if $f(x) \leq g(x)$ then $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \leq \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x)$ (Same for the discrete case)